# Le mot "sérendipité"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, anglicismes, science

Le mot "sérendipité" vient du mot anglais "serendipity" ([[1]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/serendipity), [[2]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%C3%A9rendipit%C3%A9), [[3]](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rendipit%C3%A9#D%C3%A9finitions)). Est-ce un mot répandu en France ? Peut-on l'employer couramment pour exprimer

> (...) le fait de réaliser une découverte scientifique ou une invention technique de façon inattendue à la suite d'un concours de circonstances fortuites et très souvent dans le cadre d'une recherche concernant un autre sujet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il n'est pas dans le TLFi parce qu'il n'est vraiment utilisé que [depuis à peu près 1980](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=s%C3%A9rendipit%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cs%C3%A9rendipit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0).

D'après ce dictionnaire, [le larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s%c3%a9rendipit%c3%a9/186748), on peut l'employer exactement comme vous l'indiquez.

Une explication beaucoup plus riche se trouve [ici](https://www.laculturegenerale.com/serendipite-definition-etymolgie-exemples/).

Ce terme semble acceptable à [l'Ac.](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/serendipite).

Answer (score 4):

Un complément pour présenter deux autres sources... D'abord la *BDL* qui approuve sans réserve le mot pour la « faculté de discerner l'intérêt, la portée d'une découverte inattendue lors d'une recherche » :

> Le terme *sérendipité*, calque morphologique de l'anglais *serendipity*,
>   dérive du nom propre Serendip (ancien nom du Sri Lanka) et du conte
>   qui y est associé, duquel sont inspirés les fondements mêmes de la
>   sérendipité, et du suffixe *-ité*. Il s'intègre parfaitement au
>   système du français.
>
> [ Grand dictionnaire terminologique (GDT/OQLF), [*sérendipité*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8458038) ]

Puis le *DHLF* qui, après avoir retracé sa diffusion (2008) et son origine (en anglais chez Walpole en 1774 dans le conte ; puis Merton dans les années 1960 en sociologie des sciences ; et l'application des développements de la théorie de l'indexation en scientométrie (Smith, 1964) aux moteurs de recherche sur Internet qui propulse le terme dans l'usage et qui fait qu'on le retrouve dans plusieurs langues etc.), en traite en ces mots :

> Si la notion est importante en épistémologie, en théorie cognitive
>   comme dans les technologies de l'information et de la documentation,
>   le mot en cinq syllabes, longueur inaccoutumée pour un emprunt, et qui
>   correspond exactement à « découverte (ou trouvaille) aléatoire », n'est
>   pas heureux en français et ne fait que témoigner d'une paresse
>   langagière et conceptuelle, alors que son emploi en anglo-américain
>   est l'exploitation technique et commerciale d'une notion poétique et
>   intellectuelle de l'époque des Lumières.
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (dir. A. Rey,
>   Robert, 2011), *sérendipité* ]

Ouch, alors que pour l'[Académie](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/serendipite) comme on l'a évoqué ailleurs, « depuis une dizaine d’années, le nom *sérendipité* est entré dans l’usage en français » et l'on ne fait que rappeler comme à la BDL que l'on peut aussi employer [*fortuité*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fortuit%C3%A9). Personnellement je trouve que des mots comme *[opportunisme](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/opportunisme)* (malgré sa connotation parfois péjorative) ou la *[propension](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/propension) à* peuvent aussi être parfois utiles pour expliquer ce dont il est question.

---

Le mot est récemment entré dans l'usage et s'emploie couramment dans le monde scientifique (Ac.). Si on veut s'assurer d'être compris par des non initiés on l'accompagnera d'une définition ou on choisira un terme plus usuel, comme *découverte*, qu'on qualifiera (*aléatoire*) ou qu'on intégrera à d'autres substantifs (*fait de, propension à, art de* etc.) selon la nuance de l'[emploi](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%C3%A9rendipit%C3%A9)...

Answer (score 2):

Il est peu connu, encore moins que *[procrastination](https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/procrastination)*, peut-être un peu plus que *[(réflexe) sternutatoire](https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/sternutatoire)*

Ces mots doivent être expliqués en public et utilisés avec malice entre amis.

Comment: Tout dépend des milieux. On le trouve dans des textes de niveau universitaire. Bien sûr il ne fait pas partie de la conversation courante, mais en anglais non plus il ne fait pas partie de la conversation de tous les jours.

Answer (score 2):

Complément aux excellentes réponses ; voici un article pertinent sur le mot (venant de 2010 quand même) :

> Le concept de l’année qui fait bonne fortune dans les sciences humaines est un mot impossible à mémoriser. « Sérendipité » ne figure même pas dans les dictionnaires français. Issu de serendipity, il signifie « don de faire des trouvailles ».

https://www.scienceshumaines.com/serendipite-mot-de-l-annee_fr_24741.html

Un autre article plus récent :

> L’un des plus fameux exemples de sérendipité est probablement la découverte de la pénicilline. Son inventeur, Alexander Fleming, découvrit en effet les propriétés de cette substance par hasard lors d’un retour de vacances. Il constata que les moisissures de pénicilline avait tué les bactéries contenues dans une boite à pétri qu’il utilisait pour ses recherches. Aujourd'hui, le sens de ce mot s’est étendu pour désigner plus généralement les heureux accidents.

https://www.out-the-box.fr/serendipite-sa-definition-et-comment-lutiliser-a-votre-avantage/

Voici le [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=s%C3%A9rendipit%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cs%C3%A9rendipit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0) du mot.

Le mot existe en français ; une fois qu'on explique avec une périphrase son sens je crois que l'on peut l'employer.

Comment: Le premier emploi de sérendipité date de 1953 dans une traduction d'un texte anglais de Darwin et employé directement en français sans passer par une traduction, en 1968 dans un texte scientifique. Je le rencontre régulièrement dans des textes écrits par des universitaires sans qu'il soit besoin de passer par une quelconque explication ou périphrase. Cependant le mot ne fait pas plus partie de la conversation courante des Français qu'il ne l'est de celle des Anglais.