# Combien de syllabes comporte typiquement/au plus un mot emprunté etc. ?

Tags: histoire, lexique, emprunts

Je [lis](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/39626) qu'un [emprunt](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emprunt_(linguistique)) particulier est un mot de cinq syllabes, « longueur inaccoutumée pour un emprunt » (DHLF).

- Quelle est la longueur typique (moyenne ?) d'un mot qui est un
  emprunt (en français) ; peut-on donner une idée du découpage selon
  le nombre de syllabes/sons ; est-ce uniforme à travers les époques ; le constat diffère-t-il entre les emprunts et les mots en général ?
- Quel emprunt dispose du plus grand nombre de syllabes ?

Comment: Ça ferait un bon sujet de thèse de doctorat.

Comment: Bien que pas emprunté, le plus grand nombre de syllabes devrait appartenir à *an-ti-con-sti-tu-tio-nnel-le-ment*… impossible à contracter !

Comment: @cl-r Voir aussi [ici](https://www.lapresse.ca/suite/201812/05/01-5206902-les-bizarreries-de-la-langue-francaise.php) pour d'autres curiosités qui pourraient encourager la réflexion...

Comment: @sinopleincandescent — … en effet, mérite le détour !

Comment: Ma fille étant en pleine phase d'apprentissage de la lecture, j'arrive avec *my 2 cents* pour signaler qu'il convient aussi de différencier les syllabes écrites et les syllabes orales.

Comment: @LaurentS. En quoi diffèrent les syllabes écrites? Je croyais que la découpe en syllabes, même à l'écrit, servaient principalement à décrire le phénomène oral lié. Je pourrais peut-être penser aux e caducs, qui donneraient 5 syllabes plutôt que 4 à *gé-né-ra-le-ment*. Est-ce de ça dont il est question?

Comment: @Montéedelait > Oui c'est bien de cela dont il s'agit... A l'oral, verre et ver ont le même nombre de syllabes (1), pas à l'écrit. Mais j'avoue que même adulte, on a parfois des doutes à la maison :-)

Comment: @LaurentS.—  Un *ver de terre* ou un *vert clair* ont la même prononciation avec un **É**, le **È** est ouvert, plus appuyé  pour *verre* ou pour la pantoufle de *vair* (ou les yeux *vair[on]s* d’autrefois), le *r* peut même est légèrement roulé pour le verre selon les régions.

Comment: Oui mais ca ne change rien au compte des syllabes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cinq syllabes, c’est assez long même pour un mot pris au hasard dans la langue, emprunté ou non. Quand on considère le nom des choses dans son champ de vision en un moment quelconque, on se rend rapidement compte que les termes à quatre syllabes ou plus sont assez rares, et qu’on peut exprimer une grande quantité de choses en une ou deux syllabes<sup>1</sup>.

Bien sûr, il y a des termes comme *indivisibilité* en sept syllabes ou *dérèglementation* en six, mais même un mot comme *plurisyllabique* ne comporte finalement que cinq syllabes.

Pour peu qu’un terme le moindrement long devienne courant, la langue le coupe et le recoupe, n’en maintenant que ce qui est nécessaire à sa compréhension :

- *Cinématographe*, en cinq syllabes, n’existe à peu près plus aujourd’hui. On l’a réduit d’abord à *cinéma*, puis éventuellement à *ciné* ou *cinoche*.
- *Réfrigérateur* est devenu *frigo* ou (au Québec) *frigidaire* (marque de commerce, communément prononcée *frij-dêre* en deux syllabes), voire *fridge*, probablement sous l’influence de l’anglais.
- Même des termes un peu plus courts, comme *automobile*, *télévision* ou *photographie*  ont à peu près disparu ou se sont spécialisés : l’automobile est une industrie, la photographie un art. Les objets sont le plus souvent des autos ou des photos.

---

#### Quelques longs emprunts et leur potentiel au raccourcissement

Que faire d’un terme comme ***sérendipité*** ? Impossible, à première vue, de couper un mot si rare que bien des gens ne le connaissent pas du tout et ne l’ont jamais même entendu, tout en maintenant un semblant de signification qui sera compris. Quand on s’attend à ce qu’une partie d’un auditoire doive demander ou chercher la signification d’un terme, on ne le coupe pas. Ce serait d’une cuistrerie méprisable. De plus, le suffixe *-ité*, français même s’il mimique ici le suffixe *-ity* de l’anglais, est porteur d’une information que l’on serait bien malvenu d’escamoter. Il semble que ce terme doive rester tout d’un bloc, tout au moins pour le moment.

En cinq syllabes aussi, ***aficionado***, emprunté à l’espagnol. Peut-être certains milieux coupent-ils en *aficio*, mais je n’en ai pas l’expérience personnelle, et il semblerait du moins selon [ce nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aficionado%2Caficionados%2Caficio%2Caficios&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caficionado%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caficionados%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caficionado%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caficionados%3B%2Cc0) que l’écrit n’ait pas encore été touché :

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Au hasard, au sommet d'une colline, je vois: le panorama<sup>4</sup>, des arbres<sup>1</sup> : épinettes<sup>3</sup>, bouleaux<sup>2</sup>, peupliers<sup>3</sup>, pins<sup>1</sup>, sapins<sup>2</sup>, mélèzes<sup>2</sup>, érables<sup>2</sup>, chênes<sup>1</sup>, etc., du lichen<sup>2</sup> forme un tapis<sup>2</sup> de mousse<sup>1</sup>, des champignons<sup>3</sup> poussent dans les endroits<sup>2</sup> plus à l’ombre<sup>1</sup> près des troncs<sup>1</sup>, dans l’humus<sup>2</sup> créé par la putréfaction<sup>4</sup> des feuilles<sup>1</sup>, des épines<sup>2</sup>, de l’écorce<sup>2</sup> et du bois<sup>1</sup> de branches<sup>1</sup> mortes accumulées au fil<sup>1</sup> des ans<sup>1</sup>. Je vois aussi le sentier<sup>2</sup> qui m’a mené au sommet<sup>2</sup>, le ciel<sup>1</sup> dans lequel passent des nuages<sup>1 ou 2</sup> qui cachent parfois le soleil<sup>2</sup>, parfois un avion<sup>2</sup> laisse une trace<sup>1</sup> de vapeur<sup>2</sup> et un hélicoptère<sup>4</sup> (hélico<sup>3</sup>) est même brièvement apparu. Il y a des cailloux<sup>2</sup>, de la forêt<sup>2</sup>, des herbes<sup>1</sup>, du foin<sup>1</sup>. Pour cette petite expédition<sup>4</sup>, j’ai enfilé mes bottes<sup>1</sup> de randonnée<sup>3</sup>, mon chapeau<sup>2</sup>, mes lunettes<sup>2</sup> fumées, j’ai mis une petite collation<sup>3</sup> dans mon sac à dos<sup>disons 3</sup>, ainsi que mon habit<sup>2</sup> de pluie<sup>1</sup>, car on ne sait jamais, et mes jumelles<sup>2</sup>. J’y suis allé avec un compagnon<sup>3</sup>. Nous observons un moment<sup>2</sup> un écureuil<sup>3</sup> qui va cacher des noisettes<sup>2</sup>. Tout en bas<sup>1</sup>, on peut voir la mer<sup>1</sup> poussant ses embruns<sup>2</sup> sur les côtes<sup>1</sup>, une ville<sup>1</sup> et sa silhouette<sup>2 ou 3</sup> de grattes-ciel<sup>2</sup> et de clochers<sup>2</sup>, la campagne<sup>2</sup>, la plaine<sup>1</sup> où se fait de l’agriculture<sup>4</sup>, une route<sup>1</sup>, des véhicules<sup>3</sup>, du trafic<sup>2</sup>, un embouteillage<sup>4</sup>. Nous entendons du bruit<sup>1</sup>, des sons<sup>1</sup>, des craquements<sup>2</sup>, des bruissements<sup>2</sup>, un bourdonnement<sup>3</sup>, une conversation<sup>4</sup>, des pas<sup>1</sup>, ...</sub>

<sub>On voit le patron, non ?</sub>

Comment: La description des lieux était bien pittoresque et c'était un moyen ingénieux de constituer un petit corpus pour l'analyse et c'est révélateur. Il est vrai qu'une partie de la réflexion est applicable à l'ensemble des mots. Peut-être mettre _aficionado_ en gras lors d'une modif. dans le sens que c'est un élément essentiel comme je sais qu'_anticonstitutionnellement_ est un des plus longs mots, je me dis que c'est un truc que je devrais savoir pour l'emprunt...