# How would you translate "survivability"?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, informatique

How would you translate survivability in French in [such context](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-24063-3_8):

> Network **Survivability** is a term that refers to the ability of the
> network to maintain an acceptable level of service during a network or
> equipment failure or traffic signal degradation. There are several
> **survivability** mechanisms covering a wide range of network architectures, technologies, and allocation of network resources.

Unfortunately, there is no French wikipedia page for ["Survivability"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivability).

What do you think of:

> Network survivability -> Réseau avec capacité de survie

Comment: Possibly useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability ie. since resilience is either an hyperonym for survivability or used interchangeably and since there is a request to merge the former with HA on Wikipedia as a subset or feature thereof.

Comment: "Network survivability" ce serait plutôt "Capacité de survie du réseau" :-)

Answer (score 4):

First time I read about this concept, here are the french terms that come to my mind :

- résilience

> Informatique
> 4. Capacité d'un système à continuer à fonctionner, même en cas de panne.
> (https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/r%C3%A9silience/68616)

- robustesse

> robuste : Qui est solidement construit et capable de résister à des efforts extrêmes et à un usage prolongé
> (https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/robuste/69655)

Answer (score 1):

> capacité de survie

([Voir, par exemple, ici](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/survivability.html))

But in the given context it is more likely

> Robustesse

aka [robustness](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustesse_(ing%C3%A9nierie))

Comment: *robustesse* with an e at the end.

Comment: @XouDo thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a thesis, a paper, a report or something similar I would suggest that in the abstract/introduction you define the term. For instance:

> Le « Network Survivability », en français, la capacité de survie du
> réseau est un terme qui désigne la capacité du réseau à maintenir un niveau de service acceptable lors d'une panne de réseau ou d'équipement ou d'une dégradation des signaux de trafic.

Once defined it may be used as it is.

By the way, *survivabilité* exists in French: https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/definition/survivabilite

> (Par extension) Capacité à rester utilisable malgré des destructions.
> La survivabilité du système dissuasif chinois est une caractéristique
> critique étant donnée la précision des armées américaines, d'autant
> que les capacités de détection d'attaque de la Chine sont incertaines.
> — (Édouard Valensi, La dissuasion nucléaire: Les terrifiants outils de
> la paix, L'Harmattan, 2012, page 188)

I think it is a neologism influenced by the English *survivability*.
[Some years ago, I posted a similar [question for serendipity and sérendipité](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39578/le-mot-s%C3%A9rendipit%C3%A9).]

Thus, one may continue the translation as follows:

> Il existe plusieurs mécanismes de « survivabilité » couvrant un large éventail d'architectures de réseau, de technologies et d'allocations de ressources de réseau.

Answer (score 0):

« Survie » est une possibilité qui semble difficile à critiquer.

> ([TlFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/survie)) B. − [À propos d'un inanimé]
> **1.** **Maintien d'une activité, d'un processus au delà d'un terme où il risque de s'interrompre.** Assurer la survie d'une entreprise. Je voyais peu de monde, entretenais la survie pénible d'une ou deux liaisons fatiguées (Camus, Chute, 1956, p. 1528).
> **2.** **Fait qu'une institution, qu'une pratique sociale, etc. se maintienne après la disparition des circonstances qui l'ont produite**. Synon. usuel *survivance*. L'instinct religieux survit à l'abandon de toute religion. La survie de cet instinct est visible chez nos instituteurs (Barrès, Cahiers, t. 8, 1910, p. 56).Si, comme je le crois, on peut établir les chances de durée d'une œuvre en tenant compte à la fois de sa véracité et de la puissance de suggestion poétique qu'elle renferme, À la Recherche du temps perdu est sans doute le seul ouvrage contemporain dont la survie ne saurait être mise en doute (Mauriac, Journal 2, 1937, p. 153).

Le terme « persistance » a un certain attrait en cela qu'on l'emploie déjà pour un phénomène quasi-physique puisque c'est un phénomène physiologique ; je veux parler de la persistance rétinienne. On se limite ainsi à un terme qui n'est pas associé aux complexités beaucoup plus imprévisibles de la vie.

Un autre terme présente un avantage similaire ; c'est « rémanence », un terme très utile en physique.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9manence))**1.** PHYSIQUE
> **a)** **Persistance partielle d'un phénomène après disparition de la cause qui l'a provoqué.** Faible, forte, longue rémanence. S'il y a rémanence − dans l'acier dur par exemple − c'est que la désorientation des domaines ne se poursuit pas jusqu'au bout (Hist. gén. sc., t. 3, vol. 2, 1964, p. 242).
> **b)** "**Aimantation résiduelle d'une substance ferromagnétique lorsque le champ magnétisant s'annule**" (Pir. 1964).
> **c)** "**Rémanence (d'un écran fluorescent). Persistance temporaire de l'émission lumineuse d'un écran fluorescent après cessation de l'excitation**" (Radiogr. 1979).

Je peux penser à un dernier terme de la physique qui présenterait un intérêt : « hystérétique ».

> **[hystérétique](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hyst%C3%A9r%C3%A9sis)** d'apr. le gr. υ ̔ σ τ ε ́ ρ η σ ι ς « manque, indigence, dénuement », dér. de υ ̔ σ τ ε ρ ε ́ ω « être en retard; manquer de ».

- Réseau à/avec capacité de survie
- Réseau à/avec capacité de persistance
- Réseau à/avec capacité de rémanence
- Réseau hystérétique

Answer (score 0):

"Survivability" means capacity of surviving. There are some words that describe this idea, e.g capacité de survie, résilience. Note that the word survivabilité actually [exists](https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/survivabilit%C3%A9) in French (it was borrowed from English).